# QuickBlox android video chat crash

Tags: android, quickblox, videochat

I was testing [Sample-videochat-android](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android) code with my Galaxy Grand Duos and Nexus 4 device. When I tried to call from user1 to user2, the call initialized but after some time the app in caller device crashed. Some time crash within 10-15 second and some time it crash after 5-6 minutes. 
Logcat:

```
W/System.err(12277): java.io.IOException: Mark has been invalidated.
W/System.err(12277): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:329)
W/System.err(12277): at java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(FilterInputStream.java:134)
W/System.err(12277): at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.receivers.TcpPacketsReceiver$TcpAudioVideoReceiverRunnab    le.run(TcpPacketsReceiver.java:83)
W/System.err(12277): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
D/QBDataReceivers(12277): before cycle: 2868
D/dalvikvm(12277): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
D/QBDataSenders(12277): sendAudioData
A/libc(12277): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xff260021 (code=1), thread 12384 (Thread-    557)
```

I know about Fatal signal 11 and I have searched it. But the native library is provided by QuickBlox so I can not test it.
Any one have any Idea how can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed. The master branch will be updated approximately in two weeks (hopefully earlier). Please feel free to follow [QuickBlox blog](http://quickblox.com/blog/) to find out when it is ready.